# Output the current status of all devices

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my PieCloudDB Database: Devices and Operations, which record the device id, name and operations performed on the device respectively.

For example:

| device_id | device_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

| operation_id | device_id | operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ON |
| 2 | 1 | OFF |
| 3 | 2 | ON |
| 4 | 3 | ON |
| 5 | 5 | ON |
| 6 | 3 | OFF |

I want to know the current status of all devices after performing these operations, I try the following sql, **but the D device does not appear in my results**(there is no record of D in the operation table). In this case it should be to output the initial state(OFF) of the device. How can I get the correct result?

```
SELECT d.device_id, d.device_name, o.operation AS current_status
FROM Devices d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT device_id, MAX(operation_id) AS max_operation_id
    FROM Operations
    GROUP BY device_id
) latest_op ON d.device_id = latest_op.device_id
INNER JOIN Operations o ON latest_op.max_operation_id = o.operation_id
ORDER BY device_id
```

| device_id | device_name | current_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | OFF |
| 2 | B | ON |
| 3 | C | OFF |
| 5 | E | ON |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join between the two tables along with the `COALESCE` function:

```sql
SELECT d.device_id, d.device_name, COALESCE(o1.status, 'OFF') AS current_status
FROM devices d
LEFT JOIN operations o1
    ON o1.device_id = d.device_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT device_id, MAX(operation_id) AS max_operation_id
    FROM operations
    GROUP BY device_id
) o2
    ON o2.device_id = o1.device_id AND
       o2.max_operation_id = o1.operation_id
ORDER BY
    d.device_id;
```

The subquery aliased as `o2` finds, for each `device_id`, the most recent `operation_id`.  This then restricts the `operations` table to the correct latest status value.  For those devices *not* appearing at all in the `operations` table, we report the status as `OFF`, using the `COALESCE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There's not D in your result because you're using inner join instead of left join.

Here's what you should do:

```sql
WITH LastOperationByDevice AS (
    SELECT
        device_id
        , MAX(operation_id) AS last_operation_id
    FROM Operations
    GROUP BY device_id
)
SELECT
    D.device_id
    , D.device_name
    , IFNULL(O.operation, 'OFF') AS current_status
FROM Devices AS D
LEFT JOIN LastOperationByDevice AS L
    ON L.device_id = D.device_id
LEFT JOIN Operations AS O
    ON
        O.device_id = L.device_id
        AND O.operation_id = L.last_operation_id
ORDER BY D.device_id
```